# MVC route in Chrome has extra question mark at end of route...why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC route that, in IE and Firefox, shows up as `http://{site}.com/{value}/`, which is the proper format I am expecting.  However, that same route in Chrome will have an extra question mark at the end; i.e. `http://{site}.com/{value}/?`.  There are no query string variables or extra data that I am passing through..also, in IE it works as it should and doesn't have the extra ? at the end of the route.

Why is there an extra ? at the end of the URL and how can I get rid of it?  I'm tasked with normalizing the URLs for our site to aid in search crawling results and this is holding up my task.  Also, will the appearance of this extra character even affect search engine crawling from Google or other companies?

edit:
I am using this value to set my route on my controller action:
`[GET("{city}-{state}-{zip}/{name}/{entity}")]`

```
public static class AttributeRouting
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // See http://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/3.-Configuration for more options.
        // To debug routes locally using the built in ASP.NET development server, go to /routes.axd
        routes.MapAttributeRoutes(config =>
        {
            config.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
            config.ScanAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            config.AddDefaultRouteConstraint(@"^entity$", new RegexRouteConstraint(@"^\d{6,7}$"));
            config.AddDefaultRouteConstraint(@"^address$", new RegexRouteConstraint(@".{3,}$"));
            config.AddDefaultRouteConstraint(@"^stateName$", new RegexRouteConstraint(@"^[^-]+$"));
            config.AddDefaultRouteConstraint(@"^page$", new RegexRouteConstraint(@"[0-9]*?$"));
        });
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `MapRoute` and usage? Put them too in question please.

Comment: Added routing details...I hope that's what you are looking for. I'm still getting use to MVC.

Comment: What are the contents of your `RegisterRoutes()` method in `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: any ideas on why Chrome adds the extra ? and whether or not it makes a difference to search crawlers?

Comment: @JasonKenyon did you ever get a solution for this?